# How to implement Firebase Google SignIn with MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, kotlin

Im building an app and Im currently facing a problem : I wrote all the events of my Google/Facebook SignIn buttons inside the LoginActivity by following the [google guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase). However, I don't want to keep business code inside the activity to follow MVVM architecture. Therefore how can I put the Firebase methods (which need an activity reference and lifecycle callbacks) ?

I've tried a LoginViewModel which is working BUT it has references to LoginActivity

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModelContext(application) {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    val Tag: String = LoginViewModel::class.java.simpleName;
    val gso: GoogleSignInOptions
    val googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    init {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(application.getString(R.string.default_client_id))
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(application, gso)
    }



    fun activityForResultLogin(requestCode:Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?, activity: Activity){
        if(requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN){
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!, activity)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(Tag, "Google sign in failed", e)
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount, activity: Activity) {
        Log.d(Tag, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.id!!)

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(Tag, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    activity.shortToast("SignInSuccess")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(Tag, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    activity.shortToast("SignInFailed")
                }

            }
    }

    fun signInGoogle(activity: Activity){
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constants.RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    fun signOutGoogle(activity: Activity){
        googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(activity){
            //Update ui
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at Paha's implementation of implementing GoogleSignIn: https://github.com/jojink/Android-Kotlin-FirebaseAuth/blob/feature/full_refactored/app/src/main/java/com/example/auth/feature/login/LoginActivity.kt

Hope this helps.

Comment: that git look more like MVP no MVVM

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: check this example from google at codelab https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-login

Comment: Hello @ELTEGANIMOHAMED ! Thanks ! It's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Can you post your answer so I can mark it as the "best answer".

Comment: @AdamaTraore glad it helped you..ok i will post it soon

Comment: Hey Adama, hope you're doing well. Would you mind posting an answer to your question with how you achieved it? It would make it easier for everyone looking for an answer as it's very hard to find anything about this online. Thank you!

Comment: I think you might be interested in reading this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have done.

create user model:

```
data class User(
    val uid: String,
    val name: String?,
    val email: String?,
    var isAuthenticated: Boolean = false,
    var isNew: Boolean? = false,
    var isCreated: Boolean = false

) : Serializable{

    constructor() : this("","","") {

    }

}
```

create AuthRepository class:

```
class AuthRepository {

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val rootRef: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val usersRef: CollectionReference = rootRef.collection(USERS)

    // Sign in using google
    fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleAuthCredential: AuthCredential): MutableLiveData<ResponseState<User>> {
        val authenticatedUserMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<ResponseState<User>> =
            MutableLiveData()
       
         firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(googleAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener { authTask ->
            if (authTask.isSuccessful) {
                var isNewUser = authTask.result?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser
                val firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = firebaseAuth.currentUser
                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    val uid = firebaseUser.uid
                    val name = firebaseUser.displayName
                    val email = firebaseUser.email
                    val user = User(uid = uid, name = name, email = email)
                    user.isNew = isNewUser
                    authenticatedUserMutableLiveData.value = ResponseState.Success(user)

                }


            } else {

                authenticatedUserMutableLiveData.value = authTask.exception?.message?.let {
                    ResponseState.Error(it)
                }

            }


        }
        return authenticatedUserMutableLiveData
    }

}
```

create LoginViewModel class:

```
class LoginViewModel constructor(private val authRepository: AuthRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    private var _authenticateUserLiveData: MutableLiveData<ResponseState<User>> = MutableLiveData()
  val authenticateUserLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<User>> get() = _authenticateUserLiveData

    fun signInWithGoogle(googleAuthCredential: AuthCredential) {
        _authenticateUserLiveData = authRepository.firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleAuthCredential)
    }


}
```

here ResponseState class is as follows:

```
sealed class ResponseState<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {


    class Success<T>(data: T) : ResponseState<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String) : ResponseState<T>(message = message)
    class Loading<T> : ResponseState<T>()

}
```

Inside your activity or fragment  you can use this as :

```
lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
private fun initGoogleSignInClient() {
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
}

private fun signInUsingGoolge() {
    val signInGoogleIntent = (activity as MainActivity).googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInGoogleIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent ? ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java) !!
                if (account != null) {
                    getGoogleAuthCredential(account)
                }

        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
        }
    }
}

private fun getGoogleAuthCredential(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    binding.progressBar.visible()
    val googleTokeId = account.idToken
    val googleAuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleTokeId, null)
    signInWithGoogleAuthCredential(googleAuthCredential)
}

private fun signInWithGoogleAuthCredential(googleAuthCredential: AuthCredential) {

    loginViewModel.signInWithGoogle(googleAuthCredential)
    loginViewModel.authenticateUserLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        authenticatedUser - >
        when(authenticatedUser) {
            is ResponseState.Error - > {
                authenticatedUser.message ? .let {
                    context ? .toast(it)
                }
            }
            is ResponseState.Success - > {
                if (authenticatedUser.data != null)
                //update ui
            }
            is ResponseState.Loading - > {
                //show progress
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for my project